How to formulate piecewise quadratic function optimization without introducing binary variables?
I have a problem with logical constraints (either-or constraints). I know that it can be solved by either big-M or complementary formulations. However, i do not want to convert it into mixed-integer problem. I found a paper that converts this either-or constraint into a continuous penalty function so that it can be solved using continuous optimization solvers.

Sonia Cafieri, Andrew R. Conn, Marcel Mongeau. The continuous quadrant penalty formulation of
logical constraints. Open Journal of Mathematical Optimization, 2023, pp.1-12. doi:10.5802/ojmo.28 https://enac.hal.science/hal-03623407v2

They proposed piecewise quadratic function to model this penalty function.
$$
g_\beta(t,f) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if }t\leq 0 \text{ or } f\geq 0\\
t^2 & \text{if }0\lt t \leq -\frac{f}{\beta}\\
\frac{1}{1-\beta^2}(t^2 + 2\beta t f +f^2) & \text{if } -\frac{f}{\beta} \lt t \lt -\beta f\\
f^2 & \text{if } -\frac{t}{\beta} \leq f \lt 0
\end{cases}
$$
The function appears to be concave (correct me if i am wrong).

I know how to formulate an optimization problem when maximizing piecewise linear concave function without introducing sos2 constraints. I don't understand how to formulate minimize piecewise quadratic concave function without introducing sos2 constraints or binary variable. can anyone help me understand how this is formulated without sos2 constraints or binary variable? Thank you in advance!

Either-or is xor, right? Can't it just be solved with linear algebra?

@command-master yes, you can if you introduce binary variables but the goal of the paper is to avoid introducing binary variables as it is easier to solve with continuous variables. I just don't understand how it can be implemented.

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4919741/how-to-formulate-piecewise-quadratic-function-optimization-without-introducing-b
